# Vertical Text Scroller jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, web, scroll

i'm searching for a jquery plugin that can scroll text in a container DIV but i can't find it.  Could anyone suggest something?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For Awesome Fun (Safari Only -includes Windows Safari too): scrolling text like star wars - http://tumblr.gesteves.com/post/261593774/im-done-star-wars-opening-crawl-using-only-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe this work for you [Simplyscroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/)

Answer (score 4):

vTicker: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/vTicker

Comment: thanks, but the problem with that plugin is that it use UL and LI component, and i have a DIV component

Answer (score 1):

vTicker site. http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/

Answer (score 1):

You can use different type of scroller from thi site
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0):

jCarousel is a jQuery plugin that should do what you're looking for.

Example: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/special_textscroller.html

Comment: same as other, i have a DIV component not a UL like jCarousel :S